# Trying to access a specific child div from a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with a little site I have been working on; I want a sort of "stream" container that holds "cards" of "content," where this "content" is some "text" as well as some "stats."

This is the HTML I currently have:

```html
<div id="stream">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">content
      <div class="text">
        blahblahblah
      </div>
      <div class="stats">
        blahblahblah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">content
      <div class="text">
        blahblahblah
      </div>
      <div class="stats">
        blahblahblah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">content
      <div class="text">
        blahblahblah
      </div>
      <div class="stats">
        blahblahblah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Eventually, I want users to be able to prepend "cards" to this "stream" as well.

Now, however, I am trying to implement some jQuery function to hide the "stats" of a card until it is clicked on. So after setting display to none in CSS of the stats, I made this in a javascript file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stream, div.card").click(function() {
    $(this).find($("div.stats")).show();
 });
});
```

It sort of works; the stats of a card are hidden until I click on a card. When I click on a card, however, all the cards' stats divs are shown.

I was hoping to somehow make it that the specific card clicked is also the (only) one that gets shown. Obviously, the current way I am doing this opens all of them as jQuery  I have selects all the cards at once; how can I remedy this?

Again, I apologize if this question has been asked; I could not seem to find something similar, and I really want this to work . . .

P.S. I tried to search for this particular instance; alot of suggestions were to just give divs ids, but this feels inconvenient when I eventually want users to prepend cards?

Comment: `$("#stream div.card").click(function() { $(this).find("div.stats").show(); });`  You don't want the `,` in your selector.  And you don't need the `$` in your find.

Comment: You have made my day! Thank you so much, it works! How can I resolve this post with your comment?

Comment: I'll do a quick answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector ->

`"#stream, div.card"`

was basically asking for all `#stream` and all `div.card`.. 
But what you really meant was,  find all `div.card` inside `#stream`. and this would be, (aka without the ,).

`"#stream div.card"`

Also you jquery find doesn't require you to convert into a jquery object, so find("div.stats") will do the trick.